# problems with AVG and LIMIT SQL

Tags: mysql

So I am asked to find the query: *Find average stars awarded by top 20 users in user reviews (most experienced). Compare it with the average stars awarded by bottom 20 users (least expereinced)*

the schema is:

**Restaurant** (name)

**Rank** (how it was ranked by Trip Advisor, it is not known what their ranking        function is!, it is NOT just SCORE)

**Score**  (average stars awarded by reviewers)

**User_Name** -  name of the reviewer/alias

**Review_Stars** - How many stars did this reviewer give to this restuarant

**Review_Date** -  The date of the review

**User_Reviews** - Total number of reviews this reviewer gave over his/her history of reviewing for hotels/resturants etc

**User_Restaurant_Reviews** - Same but just for restaurants

**User_Helpful** - How many of the user reviews were marked as helpful by other reviewers

So my logic was to select distinct user_names, and their reviews, order that by reviews and limit it to 20. When I went to add the `AVG(REVIEW_STARS)` it completely changes the answers.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT USER_NAME, USER_REVIEWS
FROM TRIPADVISOR
ORDER BY USER_REVIEWS desc
limit 20;
```

RETURNS:

`Dorian C   1329`

`Scipion-Paris  1219`

`Waddler    1213`

`CJTravelerTexas    937`

`runner-oh...   828`

`maurowave  818`

`gabrielct...   720`

`AJCG   667`

`pietro r   652`

`Albia-Newton   651`

`Jilllian   650`

`laserkid   648`

`pstiva 616`

`lucaheat   585`

`Chokk  511`

`Soracte    491`

`viaggiatr...   487`

`tornado9   479`

`Magorzata B    478`

`Marcello...    464`

When I change the query to:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT USER_NAME, USER_REVIEWS, AVG(REVIEW_STARS)
FROM TRIPADVISOR
ORDER BY USER_REVIEWS desc
limit 20;
```

It returns: 
`Iain U 60  4.3333`

I think my logic must be off in the way I am going about this but if anyone can shed some light it would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `GROUP BY` statement, and you may want to remove the `DISTINCT`. You need something along the lines of:

```
SELECT USER_NAME, USER_REVIEWS, AVG(REVIEW_STARS)
FROM TRIPADVISOR
GROUP BY USER_NAME, USER_REVIEWS
ORDER BY USER_REVIEWS desc
limit 20;
```

Comment: Wow thanks, how come I should remove the `DISTINCT` and why do I need the `GROUP BY`? Your query looks to be returning the correct data I am just curious so I can realize what I am doing wrong in the future

Comment: `DISTINCT` is pretty dumb. Basically takes all the displayed rows and ignores duplicates. `GROUP BY`, on the other hand, allow to execute the aggregate function (`AVG` in this case) over the specified columns. MySQL is weird though, since it doesn't force you to enter all columns, which may return an unexpected result set

Comment: I figured I didn't really want any duplicates because I just wanted 20 people. Does that not make sense then?

Comment: Not in this case, since the problem you were trying to solve involved grouping, and not actually removing duplicate results.